# how to Print date and id in given XML

Tags: java, android

This is my xml format:

```
<taxmann>
    <docdetails>
        <info id="104010000000006516" date="20120120">
            <physicalpath>\\192.168.1.102\CMS\DATA</physicalpath>
            <filepath isxml="N">\CIRCULARS\DIRECTTAXLAWS\HTMLFILES\CIRDGBACDD4836150012011122012012.htm</filepath>
            <summary></summary>
            <description></description>
            <heading>DGBA.CDD. NO.H- 4836 /15.02.001/2011-12 | Clarification on Regulation of Interest Rates for Small Savings Schemes</heading>
            <correspondingcitation/>
            <hasfile>YES</hasfile>
            <sortby>20120328155728957</sortby>
            <parentid></parentid>
            <parentchapterid></parentchapterid>
        </info>
    </docdetails>
</taxmann>
```

I'm able to retrieve data of heading but I want to print date and id too but I'm not able to do this. Please tell me how to implement it.

```
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url); // getting XML

    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map;

    for (int i = indexRowStart; i < indexRowEnd; i++) {
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("RowID", String.valueOf(RowID));

        String Heading= parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME).replace("|", "|\n").replace("|", "");
        map.put(KEY_NAME,Heading);

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
}
```

This is my code please tell me the logic how I can parse, so that I can get date and id too.

Comment: i don't understand where the problem is

Comment: please tel me how to get date vale ..please write the code for that coz date is in inside in another node.

Comment: what date ? what have you tried ?

Comment: date and id is inside INfo node list. how to retrieve that

Comment: <info id="104010000000006516" date="20120120">

Comment: yes to get that attribute value? please tell m me that ?

Comment: read the documentation, element has a getAttribute method

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure this is the easiest way to read that xml file? It just looks a bit too complicated. Why don't you navigate manually through the tree structure?

I would say you would get it this way:

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();     
Document doc;
doc = builder.build(file);

//rootElement would be your "taxmann" element
Element rootElement =   doc.getRootElement();
Element docdetailsElement = rootElement.getChild("docdetails");
Element infoElement = docdetailsElement.getChild("info");

String id = infoElement.getAttributeValue("id");
String date = infoElement.getAttributeValue("date");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Element#getAttribute(String name) method. In your case something like:

```
String id=e.getAttribute("id");
String date=e.getAttribute("date");
```

Comment: If e is your info node then you should be able to use getAttribute to retrieve the values. See @Decrayer answer on how to get to the info node.